# jQuery .click() being raised twice

Tags: jquery, events

This question has been asked numerous times before and I looked at the other questions, but their proposed fixes didn't apply to me.

The problem is the `.click` handler in the `collapseFieldsets()` function is being raised twice.

Here is my init function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    navigation_setup();

    collapseFieldsets();

    $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').placeholder();

    $(window).resize( function() {

        var width = $(window).width();
        $('h1').css('display', width < 1000 ? 'none' : 'block');
    } );
});
```

This is my collapseFieldsets:

```
function collapseFieldsets() {

    $("fieldset.collapseable legend").css("cursor", "pointer");
    $("fieldset.collapseable legend label").css("cursor", "pointer");

    $("fieldset.collapsed div.fieldsetContent").hide();

    $("fieldset.collapseable legend").click(function(event) {

        var fieldsetContent = $(this).parent().find("div.fieldsetContent");

        fieldsetContent.toggle(200);
    });
}
```

And this is what my HTML looks like:

```
<fieldset class="collapseable">
    <legend><label><input checked="checked" name="ClientUpdate" type="radio" value="Current" /> Mr John Smith</label></legend>
    <div class="fieldsetContent">

        <input id="ClientCurrent_PersonId" name="ClientCurrent.PersonId" type="hidden" value="9" />

        <!-- More input elements etc -->

    </div>
</fieldset>
```

The `collapseFieldsets` function is only called once - when I insert `alert` calls they only appear once.

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1, but it also happens with 1.8.0.

Comment: Add `event.preventDefault();` in your `.click()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The checkbox triggers a click event that is propagated to (and handled by) the parent.

Do you need to put the click event on the legend? if you change this:

```
$("fieldset.collapseable legend").click(function(event){...})
```

to this:

```
 $("fieldset.collapseable input").click(function(event){
    var fieldsetContent = $(this).parentsUntil('.collapseable').parent().find("div.fieldsetContent");

    fieldsetContent.toggle(200);
 })
```

It'll work.

Alternatively, you can return false in the event bound to the legend to prevent propagation

Comment: I changed it to `fieldset.collapseable legend input` and that stopped the `.click` handler from being called twice, but now the `.toggle()` call has no effect: all of my `<div class="fieldsetContent">` elements have `style="display: none;"` applied to them which isn't undone when the input element is clicked again.

Comment: @Dai thats because `this` in the event callback references the element to which the callback is bound (the `input` element). See above edit for a potential fix.

Comment: I used your `parentsUntil...` code, but now every `<div class="fieldsetContent">` is collapsed, not just those within the input's fieldset. EDIT: I realised the typo with "collapseable", but even after I fix that it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Dai try again. parentsUntil selects up to but not including the element matched by the selector. In your case, you want this element so that the subsequent `find` will work. If this still doesn't work, can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Good idea, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vVVS4/ - as you can see clicking on the radio buttons has no effect. I replaced `.toggle` for `css("display", "none")` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: The callback in your fiddle is missing a call to `parent()`. `$(this).parentsUntil('.collapseable').**parent()**.find("div.fieldsetContent")`. I somehow doubt this is the behavior you ultimately want (clicking on a unselected radio button then clicking back on the previously selected radio button hides content; also multiple divs can be expanded simultaneously) but I believe it matches the behavior of the code in your question.

Comment: ah, yes. My mistake. And yes, you're right: I want to toggle the visibility of the fieldset based on its legend's input state. Can you suggest any approaches for this?